# convert expression into general register operation Models

Tags: cpu-registers, x86-16, cpu-architecture, processor

I  would like to get some help to convert this expression into commands of 4 methods:

```
z=3*(x+2)-2*y
```

here are the methods with my tries:

**by stack:**

```
push 2
push -1
mult
push y
mult
push x
push 2
add
push 3
mult
add
pop z
```

**by accumulator:**

```
load y
mult -2
store temp
load x
add 2
mult 3
add temp
store z
```

**register-memory:**

```
add R1, x, 2
mult R1, R1, 3
mult R2, y, -2
add z, R1, R2
```

**register-register:**

```
load R1, x
add R1, R1, 2
mult R1, R1, 3
load R2, y
mult R2, R2, -2
add R1, R1, R2
store z, R1
```

is it ok? can I use negative numbers (-2...)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> addz, R1, R2
> ```

Didn't you meant to write : `add z, R1, R2` ?

Other than this the 4 methods look OK.

---

> can I use negative numbers (-2...)?

This would largely depend on the availability of commands like `neg` or `sub`.
Observe the difference if `sub` were possible:

```
push 2 \
push y | = 2*y
mult   /
push x \
push 2 |
add    | = 3*(x+2)
push 3 |
mult   /
sub     <-- Does depend on the order of the previous pushes!
pop z
```

---

The *by accumulator* version would look like this using `sub` and positive numbers only:

```
load y
mult 2
store temp
load x
add 2
mult 3
sub temp
store z
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right I meant to write: " add z, R1, R2 ". Another question: do you know what is the order of "sub" command? for example: push x push y sub what would be the operation? x-y? or y-x? is there a difference in this interpret between the 4 methods from my question? thanks again!

Comment: I can't possibly know what is the order for such a `sub` operation since I, as opposed to you, don't have a manual that tells what all of those operations do. In the _by accumulator_ version the current order would be correct as it leaves its result in the accu! (I've added this to the answer)